# 3D Touch Peek View Will not slide up for action

Tags: ios, uitableview, qlpreviewcontroller, 3dtouch

I have a table view. On 3D Touch I preview a pdf in a `QLPreviewController`. The peek and the pop work as intended.

For some reason I cannot get the preview controller view to slide up and show my action items. I am returning a valid array of UIPreviewActionItems in `(NSArray<id<UIPreviewActionItem>> *)previewActionItems`.

For some reason when peek is displayed, no amount of sliding upward moves the preview and no action items are made visible as I see in other apps.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was stuck on this for a while too. Make sure your `-previewActionItems` method is in the view controller *that you are previewing*.

[Documentation for -previewActionItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/previewActionItems)

Comment: I had this thought. Pretty sure I tried it with no joy. I will double check it, perhaps I never tested it properly. Thanks.

Comment: "that you are previewing" I've been stuck on this for so long and you just solved it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and was returning the `-previewActionsItems` from my preview view controller.

I forgot that I was wrapping this in a UINavigationController which is technically the view controller doing the previewing. I dropped this in a subclass to work round it:

```
- (NSArray<id<UIPreviewActionItem>> *)previewActionItems
{
    return self.topViewController.previewActionItems;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

previewActionItems should add in the ViewController which you want Preview not in the ViewController registerForPreviewingWithDelegate

Answer (score 2):

Now you need to override a property rather than a function.

```
override var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    return previewActions
}
```